# Cannot add data to a ComplexField using Python SDK for Azure AI Search

Tags: python, azure, indexing, azure-cognitive-search

I want to upload a payload with a nested dictionary to Azure AI Search index. I am using a ComplexField in the index for a nested dictionary in my payload. The nested dictionary is not being recognized by the index and I get a null-error. Here is my code:

```
    ComplexField,
    CorsOptions,
    SearchIndex,
    ScoringProfile,
    SearchFieldDataType,
    SimpleField,
    SearchableField,
)

request_example = {
        
            "id": "1",
            "text": "bla",
            "payload": {
                "processId": "00665",
                "color": "green"
            }
        
    }

# Create a search index  
index_client = SearchIndexClient(endpoint=service_endpoint, credential=credential)  
fields = [  
    SimpleField(name="id", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, key=True, sortable=True, filterable=True, facetable=True),  
    SearchableField(name="text", type=SearchFieldDataType.String),  
    ComplexField(
        name="payload",
        fields=[
            SimpleField(name="processId", type=SearchFieldDataType.String),
            SimpleField(name="color", type=SearchFieldDataType.String),
        ],
        collection=True,
    )
]  
  
# Configure the vector search configuration  
vector_search = VectorSearch(  
    algorithms=[  
        HnswAlgorithmConfiguration(  
            name="myHnsw",  
            kind=VectorSearchAlgorithmKind.HNSW,  
            parameters=HnswParameters(  
                m=4,  
                ef_construction=400,  
                ef_search=500,  
                metric=VectorSearchAlgorithmMetric.COSINE,  
            )  
        ),  
    ],  
    profiles=[  
        VectorSearchProfile(  
            name="myHnswProfile",  
            algorithm_configuration_name="myHnsw",   
        ),  
    ],  
)  
  
semantic_config = SemanticConfiguration(  
    name="my-semantic-config",  
    prioritized_fields=SemanticPrioritizedFields(  
        # title_field=SemanticField(field_name="title"),  
        # keywords_fields=[SemanticField(field_name="color")],  
        content_fields=[SemanticField(field_name="text")]  
    )  
)  
  
# Create the semantic settings with the configuration  
semantic_search = SemanticSearch(configurations=[semantic_config])  
cors_options = CorsOptions(allowed_origins=["*"], max_age_in_seconds=60)
from typing import List
scoring_profiles: List[ScoringProfile] = []
# Create the search index with the semantic settings  
index = SearchIndex(name="complex_field_test", fields=fields,  
                    vector_search=vector_search, semantic_search=semantic_search,scoring_profiles=scoring_profiles, cors_options=cors_options)  
result = index_client.create_or_update_index(index)  
print(f'{result.name} created')  

# Upload some documents to the index
search_client = SearchClient(endpoint=service_endpoint, index_name="complex_field_test", credential=credential)
result = search_client.upload_documents([request_example])  
print(f"Uploaded {len(documents)} documents")
```

And the error I get:

`The request is invalid. Details: A null value was found for the property named 'payload', which has the expected type 'Collection(search.complex.payload)[Nullable=False]'. The expected type 'Collection(search.complex.payload)[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values.`

So, as I understand the nested dictionary "payload" is not being recognized and appears like empty, although the sub-fields are registered in the index and have no null values. Can you help me with this problem? How to add data to a ComplexField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have set the  `collection`  attribute of the  `ComplexField`  to  `True`, which means it is expecting an array of objects instead of a single object.

If you want to store a single nested dictionary, you should set  `collection`  to  `False`.

Here's the corrected code:

```py
service_endpoint = "https://<Endpoint-Name>.search.windows.net/"
api_key = ""
index_name="complex_field_test"
credential = AzureKeyCredential(api_key)

request_example = {
    "id": "1",
    "text": "bla",
    "payload": {
        "processId": "00665",
        "color": "green"
    }
}

# Create a search index
index_client = SearchIndexClient(endpoint=service_endpoint, credential=credential)
fields = [
    SimpleField(name="id", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, key=True, sortable=True, filterable=True, facetable=True),
    SearchableField(name="text", type=SearchFieldDataType.String),
    ComplexField(
        name="payload",
        fields=[
            SimpleField(name="processId", type=SearchFieldDataType.String),
            SimpleField(name="color", type=SearchFieldDataType.String),
        ],
        collection=False, #Change this
    )
]

index = SearchIndex(name=index_name, fields=fields)
result = index_client.create_or_update_index(index)
print(f'{result.name} created')

# Upload some documents to the index
search_client = SearchClient(endpoint=service_endpoint, index_name=index_name, credential=credential)
result1 = search_client.upload_documents([request_example])
```

With above modified code, I was able to upload payload data to index.

[image]

Also, if you want to keep `collection= True`. Your sample data should follow below structure:

```json
request_example = {  
    "id": "1",  
    "text": "bla",  
    "payload": [  
        {  
            "processId": "00665",  
            "color": "green"  
        },  
        {  
            "processId": "00777",  
            "color": "red"  
        }  
    ]  
}
```